# Disable Google Play Music menu bar icon

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar, applications

Is there a way to disable the Google Play Music icon in the menu bar, while keeping Google Play Music running?

[image: Google Play Music Icon]

Answer (score 1):

If you've already tried <kbd>Command</kbd>-dragging it out of the menu bar (although draggable menu itmes are a private API feature, as pointed out by comments below and usually only works with system icons like Time Machine, clock, battery, and volume), I'd recommend

### [Bartender](http://macbartender.com) (free in beta, $7 full version)

Bartender allows you full control of your menu bar by adding a second, hidden but easily accessible menu bar to organize all of your icons. Alternatively, you could request that [Broomstick](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/42501/broomstick) (free) be updated for Google Play.

Comment: Draggable menu items are a private API feature. They are mostly system integrated menus such as clock, battery and volume and some, but rare, third-party applications like iStatMenu.

Comment: right, editing answer accordingly; thank you @MaxRied